TM1637 Decimal points
I am using the following TM1637 board with an Arduino Pro Micro clone.
I am attempting to use the "TM1637Display Library" written by Avishay Orpaz, but I cannot find any way to use the four decimal points on this display (as opposed to the colon appearing on many 4 digit displays).  Is there any way to use this driver to output one of the decimal points to the display?  If not, what is a 1637 driver which will allow me to output a decimal point?  I am going to be reading the voltages on several of the Arduino analog inputs and outputting them to the display in sequence.

There's no documentation provided by the seller, not even a pinout. Don't buy products without documentation. Now your only option is for you to experiment and find out if the decimal dots are even usable. Alternatively, you could return the displays, leave a warning for others in the reviews and buy some that do include documentation.

Additionally you can search and lookup the display's data sheet to find the pin for the decimal point. Next you need to re-engineer the display's board and check whether its control logic controls that pin at all. With some luck, it does.

@StarCat and busybee. TM1637 is a LED Display and Keypad Driver IC with a datasheet. No special pinout just data and clock and the TM1637Display library works for OP.

@Juraj There are four pins on the module without any obvious pin markings (you would at least like to know where to connect Vcc, Gnd, SDA and SCL) and the product description says nothing about I2C. Anyway, it was just an example of the fact that this is a module that is unsupported by its seller and when you buy one, you're on your own.

@StarCat sorry it is not I2C but a similar two wire protocol. I edited the comment. the TM1637  IC has a datasheet

OK, it definitely works.  I found a test sketch that displays all four decimal points.  See my answer.  These boards are extremely common, available on ebay, Amazon, and elsewhere.

I found this (edited for relevance)
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <TM1637Display.h>

// Module connection pins (Digital Pins)
#define CLK 4
#define DIO 3

// Create a new instance of the TM1637Display class
TM1637Display display(CLK, DIO);

// The amount of time (in milliseconds) between tests
#define TEST_DELAY   2000

void setup() {};


void loop()
{
  int k;
  uint8_t data[]  = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff }; // Create an array that turns all segments ON
  uint8_t blank[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // Create an array that turns all segments OFF
  display.setBrightness(0x0f);

  // All segments on
  display.setSegments(data);
  delay(TEST_DELAY);
  
    // Run through all the dots
    for(k=0; k <= 4; k++) {
        display.showNumberDecEx(0, (0x80 >> k), true);
        delay(TEST_DELAY);
    }
}


The example of  Avishay Orpaz's TM1637Display library has this:
// Run through all the dots
for(k=0; k <= 4; k++) {
  display.showNumberDecEx(0, (0x80 >> k), true);
  delay(TEST_DELAY); // show the dot
}

If you use display.setSegments and encode the segments in the sketch, the dot is the 8 bit in the byte encoding the segments of the digit.
displayData[i] = display.encodeDigit(digit[i])
displayData[i] |= 0x80; // show the dot


from the TM1631Display.h, the showNumberDecEx() method support the dot enable, and it is not exactly the MSB for controlling the dot, but it is bit shift mask depend on the which digit's dot to be enabled.

@hcheung yes. as the answer says

Oops!  I was writing my answer when you posted yours.  Thanks.
